# Stylus pressure not working ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3G on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, x-server, gimp, wacom

I recently got an ThinkPad X1 Yoga (3rd generation) with an integrated stylus. Debian Buster (10 RC1) is installed. I'm using the Cinnamon desktop environment.

The stylus works nicely as a generic pointing device, but it seems the pressure sensitivity of the stylus is not detected.

I enabled the stylus/eraser devices in Gimp to test. But in tutorials there sometimes seems to be a pressure device as well. There is no pressure device listed for me.

In Xournal, if I set the program to recognize pressure, the text looks a bit different, but I am not sure if it is actually using the pressure sensitivity.

What can be done to fix or at least further debug this problem?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Yoga_(Gen_3)#Tablet_Functions => https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wacom_tablet#Pressure_curve , https://linuxwacom.github.io/

Comment: Are you using a paint dynamic with the paint tool that makes use of pressure for something, for example size or opacity?